Stop Sphinx from executing function in pytest mark?
I am using sphinx to make documentation for my tests. My code looks like this
@pytest.mark.parameterize(some_func()), scope = session)
class testClass:
    def test_case1():
    def testcase2():

In a normal flow, some_func() will return a set of values which can be applied for all tests.
The problem is sphinx keeps executing the function in the pytest mark, which takes a lot of time and create unnecessary data.
I know since in the resulting html I can see the pytestmark with all the parameters from executing the function, and also because it outputs the function log to the console.
I have tried both :exclude-member: and :no-undoc-member:, but they did not do anything for this case.
How do I stop sphinx from executing the function in my pytest mark?
